# Data type for not getting SUM of data in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have few MySQL tables which I need to get sum of the data from them. There in PHP I use a common code for all of these after I selected particular table I want from a drop down list.

```
      $result3 = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table_name." ");
            if (!$result3) {
                echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysqli_error($con);
                exit;
            }
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

                    $topics[] = $row3['Field'];

                }
            }
```

when I get column names of the SQL table to the array $topic using that array I am getting the sum of each table column

```
  for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($topics);$x++){
                $for_sum= "SUM(".$topics[$x].")";
                $new_array_sum[]=$for_sum;
            }

  $comma_separated = implode(",", $new_array_sum);     

  $sql=" SELECT ".$comma_separated."FROM $table_name
```

This works well and my problem is when I have columns in some tables that I don't need sum such as ID s what data type in SQL I should define the column to get sum as zero or meaningfull thing. I tried with VARCHAR  and still it gives sum.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html

MySQL converts the expression to numeric when the expression is evaluated in a numeric context